# I want to explode a variable in a little different way

Tags: php

I have this variable.

```
$var = "A,B,C,D,'1,2,3,4,5,6',E,F";
```

I want to explode it so that I get the following array.

```
array(
[0] => A,
[1] => B,
[2] => C,
[3] => D,
[4] => 1,2,3,4,5,6,
[5] => E,
[6] => F
);
```

I used `explode(',',$var)` but I am not getting my desired output. Any suggestions?

Comment: What you need is a CSV parser.

Comment: Please explode strings, not your code :-)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

There is an existing function that can parse your comma-separated string. The function is [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

It's signature is like so:

```
array str_getcsv ( string $input [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape = "\\" ]]] )
```

Your only change would be to change the 3rd variable, the enclosure, to single quotes rather than the default double quotes.

Here is a sample.

```
$var = "A,B,C,D,'1,2,3,4,5,6',E,F";
$array = str_getcsv($var,',',"'");
```

If you `var_dump` the array, you'll get the format you wanted:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "B"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "D"
  [4]=>
  string(11) "1,2,3,4,5,6"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "E"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "F"
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Simply use `preg_match_all` with the following regex as follows

```
preg_match_all("/(?<=').*(?=')|\w+/",$var,$m);
print_r($m[0]);
```

**Regex Explanation :**

- `(?<=').*(?=')` Capture each and every character within `'(quotes)`
- `|\w+` `|(OR)` Will grab rest of the characters except `,`

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/460549)

[**Regex**](https://regex101.com/r/tW9zD1/2)

Comment: I dont want ' ' before and after 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: Hi @Uchiha can you explain the regexp? Please.

Answer (score 6):

Although `preg_split` along with `array_map` is working very good, see below an example using `explode` and `trim`

```
$var = "A,B,C,D,'1,2,3,4,5,6',E,F";

$a = explode("'",$var);

//print_r($a);
/*
outputs
Array
(
    [0] => A,B,C,D,
    [1] => 1,2,3,4,5,6
    [2] => ,E,F
)
*/
$firstPart = explode(',',trim($a[0],',')); //take out the trailing comma
/*
print_r($firstPart);
outputs
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
)
*/
$secondPart = array($a[1]);

$thirdPart = explode(',',trim($a[2],',')); //tale out the leading comma
/*
print_r($thirdPart);
Array
(
    [0] => E
    [1] => F
)
*/

$fullArray = array_merge($firstPart,$secondPart,$thirdPart);
print_r($fullArray);
/*
ouputs
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
    [4] => 1,2,3,4,5,6
    [5] => E
    [6] => F
)
*/
```

Comment: it's not *that* good, I posted the answer for the sake of completeness, I liked yours and @Pupil's better to be honest :)

Comment: But over here, we are bounding the program that the middle part will consist of ' '. I want it to be generic. The code code be anything. There could be multiple `'1,2,3'` inside it.

Answer (score 5):

You need to explode the string to array.

But, you need commas after every element except last one.

Here is working example:

```
<?php
$var = "A,B,C,D,'1,2,3,4,5,6',E,F";
$arr = explode("'", $var);
$num = ! empty($arr[1]) ? str_replace(',', '_', $arr[1]) : '';
$nt = $arr[0] . $num . $arr[2]; 
$nt = explode(',', $nt);
$len = count($nt);
$na = array();
$cnt = 0;
foreach ($nt as $v) {
    $v = str_replace('_', ',', $v);
    $v .= ($cnt != $len - 1) ? ',' : '';
    $na[] = $v;
    ++$cnt; 
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/459902)

Comment: I am not getting my desired output.

Comment: Hi @Uchiha, thanks for your sportsmanship. But, your answer is 10 times better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = "A,B,C,D,'1,2,3,4,5,6',E,F";

$arr = preg_split("/(,)(?=(?:[^']|'[^']*')*$)/",$var);
foreach ($arr as $data) {
    $requiredData[] = str_replace("'","",$data);
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($requiredData);
```

**Description :**
Regular Exp. :-

```
(?<=').*(?=') => Used to get all characters within single quotes(' '),

|\w+ |(OR) => Used to get rest of characters excepted comma(,)
```

Then Within foreach loop i'm replacing single quote

Comment: A description of what the code does would increase the quality of this answer.

Comment: This is going to explode if you want ' s in your result. And you don't really need to group the comma.

Comment: This is hard to understand at first glance (and probably at second glance, and third), especially in comparison to the correct answer, `str_getcsv()`.

Comment: I bet this is wrong for `"A,B,C,D,'1,2,3,''4,5,6',E,F";`. *You can't build a parser with regex*.

Comment: Regular Exp. :-
    (?<=').*(?=') => Used to get all characters within single quotes(' ')
    |\w+ |(OR) => Used to get rest of characters excepted comma(,)
Then Within foreach loop i'm replacing single quote