# how to write a regex to remove extra commas from string for making a csv

Tags: php, regex

how to write a regex to remove extra commas from string for making a csv:-

Explanation:-
Basically I am getting this kind of data in a string:-
  `$string = 'abc,bcd,cdf, "af,cv"'`

this is a sample string and I want to make csv from that string.
Now I want to remove that extra comma between af and cv but not the other commas. Can someone help in writing the regex.

Comment: You learn regex, quiet simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to explode a variable in a little different way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429500/i-want-to-explode-a-variable-in-a-little-different-way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this will resolve your issue:-

```
$result_1 = "STRING containing extra  commas"
$regex = '/"(.+?)"/';
preg_match_all($regex, $result_1, $matches);
$x = 0; $max = count($matches[0]);
while($x < $max){
  $replace = str_replace(",", ".", $matches[1][$x]);
  $result_1 = str_replace($matches[0][$x], $replace, $result_1);
  $x++;
}
print_r($result_1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the instant reply..that resolved the issue